# Is possible to run the jsc (JavaScriptCore) utility from the command line in Ubuntu, like in OSX?

Tags: console, javascript, webkit

In OSX there is a hidden utility called `jsc`, part of WebKit, that can be used to run JavaScript code on the command line. It can be used as a JavaScript console, like `irb` for Ruby.

I have the `libwebkitgtk-3.0` and `-3.0-dev` libraries installed, but I cannot figure out how to find or build `jsc`. Is it even possible?

Note: I already know about alternatives like Rhino, SpiderMonkey, etc.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Install [image: a link to install] [rhino](https://packages.ubuntu.com/rhino) and use `rhino-jsc` (see [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/lucid/man1/rhino-jsc.1.html))

Answer (score 3):

Another solution is to install nodejs:

```
sudo apt-get install nodejs npm
```

The above will not always install the most recent version, in which case you can try:

```
sudo apt-get install python-software-properties python g++ make
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:chris-lea/node.js
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nodejs
```

Answer (score 2):

If you prefer to avoid Rhino and stick with the WebKitGTK+ packages, install [[image: a link to install] libjavascriptcoregtk](https://packages.ubuntu.com/libjavascriptcoregtk) and use `/usr/bin/jsc` ([manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/man1/jsc.1.html))